# Mobile app to practice rhythm

Tags: ios, music, educational, music-composing

Do you know any mobil app where user can add music notes into a sheet music, with varying delay between music notes and user can try drumming the song, with correct delays, by tapping the screen of the phone?! If user make a mistake app would draw ones attention.

Comment: For which mobile operating system(s)? Are you fine with paying for it?

Comment: first of all iOS

Answer (score -1):

For PC software, I suggest Finale and Sibelius 7. For me I use **Sibelius 7** because it can be downloaded free if you searched online.

In mobile apps, I currently use android Google Play,  **Ensemble Composer**. This is a good app for you to compose and edit the notes and rhythms you like.

I recommend strongly on PC Sibelius 7 because ***with PC software, you can easily make the music sheet you want*** so that you can compose more flexible with mouse rather than your fingers.

Comment: It does not allow the user to practice rhythm, right?